# How can I test a method that is supposed to be loaded on a component mount on a funcional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

So I created a method to add the attribute `target` to every anchor on some specific cases.

```
/**
 * This method adds the attr target _blank to the anchors missing it.
 */

export const handleAnchors = (): void => {
  const getBody: HTMLCollectionOf<Element> = document.getElementsByClassName('rendered-markup');

  if (getBody) {
    for (let i = 0; i < getBody.length; i++) {
      const anchors = getBody[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
      if (anchors && anchors.length) {
        for (let j = 0; j < anchors.length; j++) {
          anchors[j].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

It works perfect for example on this component:

```
import { handleAnchors } from '../utils/customHooks';

export const RenderedMarkup: FC<RenderedMarkupProps> = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    handleAnchors();
  }, [props.markup]);

  return (
    <div
      className={`rendered-markup ${props.className}`}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: createDOMPurify.sanitize(props.markup) }}
    />
  );
};
```

But when I try to test it:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as customHooks from './customHooks';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

jest.mock('./customHooks.ts');

export type Props = {
  markup: string;
};

const TestComp: React.FC<Props> = (props): JSX.Element => {
  useEffect(() => {
    customHooks.handleAnchors();
  }, [props.markup]);

  return (
    <div className="rendered-markup undefined"><a href={props.markup}>GOOGLE</a></div>
  );
};

describe('handleAnchors', () => {
  it('adds attribite target to anchor', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestComp markup="the/url/com" />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

This is the snapshot:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`handleAnchors adds attribite target to anchor 1`] = `
<div
  className="rendered-markup undefined"
>
  <a
    href="the/url/com"
  >
    GOOGLE
  </a>
</div>
`;
```

Which means the test is not working properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should wait until this attribute is added, using either the built-in methods or a custom `setTimeout` of some kind

Comment: Hi @GalAbra can you provide a code sample?

Comment: I added the time out with 1000 and it didn't work either.